# how can i loop over a variable that might have single value?

Tags: ansible

I'm writing a playbook and want to loop a role over a variable that gets its value from the user. however that value might not always be a list of items, it might be a single value and whenever that happens it throws an error.

**My Task:**

```
- name: task name
  include role:
    name: role name
  vars:
    cluster_name: '{{ item }}'
  loop: "{{ list_or_not }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: item
```

**error:**

> ...Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the: "| list" filter?
Sorry cannot test at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You could test if the variable is a string, and if so, transform it into a single-item list.  Something like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        list_or_not: ["{{ list_or_not }}"]
      when: list_or_not is string

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ list_or_not }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question, as I had the same problem.

Something similar to following worked for me (I adapted it to your example without testing if it makes sense):

```
- name: task name
  include role:
    name: role name
  vars:
    cluster_name: '{{ item }}'
  loop: "{{ list_or_not is string | ternary([list_or_not], list_or_not) }}"
```

This uses [`bool | ternary(truevalue, falsevalue)`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ternary_filter.html) where

- `truevalue` is used when bool is `true`
- `falsevalue` is used when bool is `false`
- This roughly is equivalent to `bool ? truevalue : falsevalue` in C or PHP
- This roughly is equivalent to `truevalue if bool else falsevalue` in Python

The trick is to check that the fact or variable (here `list_or_not`) which shall be passed into the `loop:` for being a string.

- If so, use a list with this as a single entry per `[ list_or_not ]`.
- If not, so the `bool` is `false`, then it is a list (hopefully) and hence hand it out unchanged as the `falsevalue` of the `ternary()` filter.

PS: Perhaps use `| ansible.builtin.ternary(` instead of just `| ternary(` to fully qualify the name